# linear algebra injective problem

Tags: linear-algebra

suppose T is a linear transformation from V to W
T is injective if and only if dim(v)≤dim(w)
is this statement true?
i solved the first : 
T is injective ==> dim(v)≤ dim(w)
which is true but i don't about the second 
dim(v)≤dim(w) ==>T is injective ??
prove or give a counterexample

Comment: $f:V\to W: v\mapsto 0_w$

Comment: a good counter example thanks

Comment: Alright, I am migrating the comment above to an answer as for you be able to accept the answer and close the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$T:V\to W: v\mapsto 0_w$$
Works irregardless of dimensions $dim(V)$ and $dim(W)$.